# Disable screen capture by disabling hardware buttons

Tags: java, android, hardware

I want do disable the possibility to screen capture whilst the user is in a certain activity, but I know that the flag secure method is not worthi trying as it has many limitations and bugs.. I tried to deactivate the volume down button with this code but if I press down button and home it keeps doing the screenshot. Is there another way to disable the screen function by deactivating the hardware buttons?

PS Is there a possibility to detect a contemporary click of two buttons like like KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN and the home button?

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
int action = event.getAction();
int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
switch (keyCode) {
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
}
return true;
default:
return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
}
```

Comment: "the flag secure method is not worthi trying as it has many limitations and bugs" -- `FLAG_SECURE` is absolutely worth using. Just be aware that it does not cover everything. "Is there another way to disable the screen function by deactivating the hardware buttons?" -- no. Besides, you do not need hardware buttons to take a screenshot.

Comment: I did the flag secure in the end ahah it works.. lot of people didn't raccomend it tho.